# Android build command failed after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build

After I updated my Android Studio it is giving me build command failed error. It gives me the following build error :

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/AndroidStudioProjects/wowtime/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target baseUrl}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libbaseUrl.so
FAILED: : && /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot /Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -L/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libbaseUrl.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libbaseUrl.so CMakeFiles/baseUrl.dir/src/cpp/baseUrl.cpp.o  -llog -latomic -lm "/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
/Users/bhaskarrajaryal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: try upgrading your cmake, sdk and ndk

Comment: I tried doing that but it still shows the same error

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue after the update. I did a clean build (under Build > Clean Project) then restarted android studio with the option "Invalidate and Restart" under File > Invalidate Caches/Restart. It run well after that

Answer (score 1):

Build-->Refresh Linked C++ Projects

Build Project

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

**Step 1:** Safely delete the `build` folder from app directory.
**Step 2:** In Android Studio, `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
**Step 3:** `Build -> Clean Project` Then `Build -> Rebuild Project`. so `build` folder will be regenerated and hope so error is gone.